# Race condition when use Kafka and JPA

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, microservices, jhipster

I have a problem when using microservice and Kafka
for example, I have Service A and Service B they communicate by Kafka and they share the same database inside the database and I have two entities A and B and they share a one-to-many relationship, when I update entity A in service A entity B gets updated/changed as wanted but when I view service B. I can't see the changes that happened in service A.

In my case example code :

**here we are in service A:**

KafkaService:

```
    public synchronized void getDriverService(Long orderId, Double longitude, Double latitude) {
    driverService.getDriver(orderId,longitude,latitude);
    driverService.collectionOrder(orderId);

}
```

driverService:

```
public void getDriver(Long orderId, Double longitude, Double latitude) {
    final Driver [] y={new Driver()};
    ascOrderRepository.findById(orderId).ifPresentOrElse(x->{
        List<DriverDTO> drivers = findAllCarNearMe(latitude, longitude);
        if(drivers.isEmpty())
            throwEmptyDriver();

        AscOrderDTO orderDto = ascOrderMapper.toDto(x);
        int check;
        for (DriverDTO dr : drivers) {
            check = checkDriver();
            if (check < 8) {
                log.debug("///////////////////////// driver accept" + dr.getId().toString());
                dr.setStatus(UNAVAILABLE);
                dr.updateTotalTrip();
                Driver driver=driverMapper.toEntity(dr);
                driver.addOrders(x);
                y[0]=driverRepository.save(driver);
                log.debug(dr.toString());
                log.debug("/////////////////////////////////////driver accept here /////////////////////////////////////////");
                break;
            }
        }
    },this::throwOrder);

}

// find All Car near me
public List<DriverDTO> findAllCarNearMe(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    checkDistance(latitude,longitude);
    Point point = createPoint(latitude, longitude);
    List<Driver> driver = driverRepository.findNearById(point, 10);
    return driverMapper.toDto(driver);

}


public void collectionOrder(Long orderId)
{
    ascOrderRepository.findById(orderId).ifPresentOrElse(y->{

        if(y.getDriver()!=null) { // here new updated and find this updated into service A
            try {
                driverProducer.driverCollectionOrder(y.getId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throwDriverNotFind();
        }

    },this::throwOrder);

}
```

This is Producer:

```
     @Component public class DriverProducer { 
    public
  DriverProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate)   {
            this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;     }
     
            public void driverCollectionOrder(Long orderId) throws Exception{           ObjectMapper obj=new ObjectMapper();
                kafkaTemplate.send("collecting",obj.writeValueAsString(orderId));
     
        }
```

**Service B**:

This is Consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "collecting",groupId= groupId)
public void doneOrderStatus(String data) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
    try
    {
        log.debug("i am in done order status order consumer");

        OrderEvent event=OrderEvent.TO_BE_COLLECTED;
        orderService.changeStatus(event, Long.parseLong(data));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This Method Has my Error:

```
    public void changeStatus(OrderEvent event, Long orderId) throws Exception {
    try {
        Optional<AscOrder> order=ascOrderRepository.findById(orderId);
        if (!order.isPresent()) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("cannot find Order", "Order entity", "Id invalid");
        }

        if(order.get().getDriver()!=null) { // cant find Change Here
            log.debug("===============================================================================================");
            log.debug(order.get().getDriver().toString());
            log.debug("===============================================================================================");
        }
        log.debug("i am in changeStatus ");
        stateMachineHandler.stateMachine(event, orderId);
        stateMachineHandler.handling(orderId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I understood your problem, but I didn't understood what is the process, actually. Who is the producer and who is the consumer? Both of the services are consumers of the same topic? What's the flow of the data?

Comment: i am editing Question with adding producer class and consumer class @MatheusCirillo

Comment: Have in mind that sharing databse between multiple microservices is an anti-pattern because it creates a tight coupling, it goes against one of the principles of microservices architecture. Anyway, after the execution of Service A, have you tried to access the database from command line or from a studio, and then query the data to see if the changes are there?

Comment: @MatheusCirillo i can see the changes only when i execute this method     {driverService.getDriver(orderId,longitude,latitude);} ,otherwise i can't see the changes.

Comment: the each method used in this process worked update or create when run any method without kafka its run and successful process
but this problem become when run kafka with each method @MatheusCirillo

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be about the separate ORM sessions held by the services.
To overcome this you may try to reload the entity. To do that,

1- wire the entity manager

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
```

2- Decorate changeStatus function with @Transactional annotation, unless there is an active transaction already going on.

3- Refresh the order entity

```
entityManager.refresh(order)
```